# Adding Word document to OneNote 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-onenote-2010

I have a number of Word 2010 documents I want to add directly into OneNote.  Is this possible, and if it is, how can it be done?

I am using a small netbook (Windows 7 Home Basic), so answers that involve keyboard shortcuts over mouse usage are preferred.  Also, having windows side-by-side is problematic due to the tiny screen.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you !

[Here !](http://www.technologyquestions.com/technology/microsoft-onenote/191493-sending-word-onenote.html)